# Rotating images using the arrow keys

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, keylistener

I am trying to make a racing game which uses the arrow keys to move the car(which is a image). When I click the left arrow key I want the image to rotate a certain amount of degrees to show that the car is turning. For some reason the car isn’t turning when the left arrow key is clicked and isn’t showing any error messages either. I would appreciate any help that you can give and thanks in advance!

```
//GameClass:
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class Game extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
   private Image image;
   BufferedImage images;
   private Image image2;
   private int x1, y1, velx = 0, vely = 0;
   ImageIcon I2;
   private Graphics2D g2;

   public Game() {
      x1 = 100;
      y1 = 100;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    ImageIcon I = new ImageIcon("track.jpg");
    image = I.getImage();
    I2 = new ImageIcon("RedCar.png");
    image2 = I2.getImage();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.drawImage(image2,x1,y1,25,14,null);
    repaint();
}
  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        try {
              File url = new File("RedCar.png");
              images = ImageIO.read(url);
          }
          catch(Exception r) {
              r.printStackTrace();
       }

           Graphics g = images.getGraphics();
           Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
           g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(15));


       }
       repaint();
       if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
           x1 += 5;
           velx = 1;
           vely = 0;
      }
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
           y1 -= 5;
           velx = 0;
          vely = -1;
     }
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
           y1 += 5;
           velx = 0;
           vely = 1;
       }
  }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
       vely = 0;
       velx = 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
}

//GameDemo Class:
import javax.swing.*;
public class GameDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("The Race");
        frame.setSize(600, 350);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.addKeyListener(game);
        frame.setResizable(false);
   }
   }
```

Comment: Sorry for the *extremely* late reply, but I think I've got the answer, if you'd like.

Comment: To be clear, when the user presses left, you want the car to turn left, and when the user presses right, turn right, correct?